# Object's values sorted in desecending order

Tags: javascript, sorting, object

I have this object:

```
gladiators = {
  Pesho: { Duck: '400' },
  Gladius: { Heal: '200', Support: '250', Shield: '250' }
}
```

Each gladiator has its own abilities and as values are the skill for each ability, I want to print them in desecending order by total skill, this is where I am at the moment:

```
for (let element in gladiators){ 
        console.log(`${element}: ${Object.values(gladiators[element]).map(Number).reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0)} skill`);
        for (let el in gladiators[element]){
            console.log(`- ${el} <!> ${gladiators[element][el]}`)
        }
    }
```

this code prints:

```
Pesho: 400 skill
- Duck <!> 400
Gladius: 700 skill
- Heal <!> 200
- Support <!> 250
- Shield <!> 250
```

I simply want it to print:

```
Gladius: 700 skill
- Shield <!> 250
- Support <!> 250
- Heal <!> 200
Pesho: 400 skill
- Duck <!> 400
```

I want the total skill to be in descending order, if its equal, sort in ascending order, the same for each ability the gladiator has. Please suggest me how can I make my question more clear if I have mistakes I read the guide a few times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We should be able to use Object.entries and Array.sort to arrange the objects as we wish, then print out the results:

```js
gladiators = {
  Pesho: { Duck: '400' },
  Gladius: { Heal: '200', Support: '250', Shield: '250' }
}

// Get our array of gladiators, add total skill and add sorted abilities array.
let result = Object.entries(gladiators).map(([name, glad]) => { 
    let abilities = Object.entries(glad);
    return { name, Total: abilities.reduce((acc, [k,v]) => acc + Number(v) , 0), abilities: abilities.sort(([k1,v1], [k2,v2]) => v2 - v1) };
});

// Sort the result in descending order by total skill.
result.sort((a,b) => b.Total - a.Total);

// Print out our result.
result.forEach(res => { 
    console.log(`${res.name}: ${res.Total} skill`)
    res.abilities.forEach(([k,v]) => console.log(` - ${k} <!>`,v));
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I would split your calculations into a separate array, and sort that new array before you output. For example:

```js
const gladiators = {
  Pesho: { Duck: '400' },
  Gladius: { Heal: '200', Support: '250', Shield: '250' }
}

const valueDescNameAsc = (a, b) => {
  if (a.value === b.value) return a.name.localeCompare(b.name)
  return a.value > b.value ? -1 : 1
}

// Transform data into arrays of objects (and calculate top-level value)
const gladiatorSkills = Object.entries(gladiators)
  .map(([name, skills]) => ({
    name,
    value: Object.values(skills).map(Number).reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0),
    skills: Object.entries(skills).map(([name, value]) => ({ name, value })).sort(valueDescNameAsc)
  }))
  .sort(valueDescNameAsc)

// Output the transformed gladiatorSkills data
for (let { name, value, skills } of gladiatorSkills) {
  console.log(`${name}: ${value} skill`)
  for (let { name, value } of skills) {
    console.log(`- ${name} <!> ${value}`)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Objects aren't built with order in mind. That's a job for arrays. Looking at your data it would be more suitable to have a list  of gladiators which you can manipulate with array methods, like ordering.

So in the example below I've rewritten your data as an array of objects, with nested arrays inside of them. This will guarantee that the order will be honored.

It will also make the manipulation of the code less complex, since you're just dealing with arrays there is no need for conversion. A combination of  `map`, `reduce` and `sort` will get you where you need to be.

```js
const gladiators = [
  {
    name: 'Pesho',
    stats: [
      {
        name: 'Duck',
        value: 400
      }
    ],
  },
  {
    name: 'Gladius',
    stats: [
      {
        name: 'Heal',
        value: 200
      },
      {
        name: 'Support',
        value: 300
      },
      {
        name: 'Shield',
        value: 250
      }
    ],
  },
];

gladiators

  /**
   * Calculate the total skill and
   * sort the skills based on their value.
   */
  .map(({ name, stats }) => {
    const skill = stats.reduce((acc, { value }) => acc + value, 0);
    const sortedStats = stats.sort((a, b) => b.value - a.value);
    return { name, skill, stats: sortedStats };
  })
  
  /**
   * Sort the gladiators by skill (desc)
   */
  .sort((a, b) => b.skill - a.skill)
  
  /**
   * Print the data
   */
  .forEach((gladiator) => {
    console.log(`${gladiator.name}: ${gladiator.skill}`)
    gladiator.stats.forEach(({ name, value }) => {
      console.log(`- ${name} <!> ${value}`);
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

I would simplify this issue by creating an new list, indexed on the **total skill** level, then, sort that list, and log each entry;

**Note:** This code could be simplified even more, but I've posted it like this so the steps are clear for OP;

```js
// Original data
const data = { Pesho: { Duck: '400' }, Gladius: { Heal: '200', Support: '250', Shield: '250' } };

// Index each gladiator on total skill
let indexOnTotal = {};
for (let obj of Object.entries(data)) {
  
    // Get obj value's
    const [name, skills] = obj;
  
    // Total Skill count
    const total = Object.keys(skills).reduce((sum,key)=>sum+parseFloat(skills[key]||0),0);
    
    // Add
    indexOnTotal[total] = obj;
}

// Sort
let sorted = Object.keys(indexOnTotal).sort().reverse().map(key=> ({...indexOnTotal[key],key:key}) );

// Log
for (var g in sorted) {

    // Original gladiator
    const [ name, skills, total ] = Object.values(sorted[g]);
    
     // Name + Total
     console.log(`${name} (${total} skill)`);
    
    // Skills
    for (const [name, value] of Object.entries(skills)) {
        console.log(`${name}: ${value}`);
    }
}
```

Output;

```
Gladius (700 skill)
Heal: 200
Support: 250
Shield: 250
Pesho (400 skill)
Duck: 400
```